# Задать заголовок для каждого списка

Tags: android, listview, webview

Всем бодрого дня. У меня возник вопрос. Вот у меня есть список `ListView`, при нажатие на список открывается определенный файл, на втором `Activity`, в `WebView`. Можно ли задать для каждого списка отдельный заголовок?
Если это возможно, прощу объяснить. Буду благодарен тому, кто поможет.

Вот код:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.view);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String itemname = "n" + bundle.getString("defStrID"); //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса

    Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

    //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
    String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(itemname, "raw", "ru.akmaltilloev.frameeditguide"));

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    String summary = "<!Doctype html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8></head><body>" + text + "</body></html>";
    myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/raw/", summary, "text/html", "utf-8", null); //загружаем текст в webview
}

public static String readRawTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) //читаем текст из raw
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return text.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого вам нужно будет использовать собственный `WebViewClient`. Вы переопределяете метод `onPageFinished()`, поэтому, когда новая страница завершит загрузку, вы можете установить соответствующий заголовок для `WebView`. Пример кода:

```
 WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mwebview);
 Toolbar mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            YourSecondActivity.this.setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
            YourSecondActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(view.getTitle());
        }
    });
```

Comment: @akmaltilloev устанавливает загаловок активити как у WebView

Comment: @akmaltilloev опишите немного подробнее в вопросе, какой результат вы хотите достигнуть

Comment: Например, есть список. 1. Сайты. 2. Браузеры. 3. Мессенджеры. Вот, при открытые списка "Сайты" в заголовке было написанно "Сайты", при открытые "Браузеры", в заголовке было написанно "Бразуеры" и т.д. Можно это реализовать?

Comment: @akmaltilloev Вы имеете ввиду в тулбаре, где бывает имя приложения?

Comment: Да, ToolBar....

Comment: @akmaltilloev поправил ответ для toolbar

Comment: Этот код задаёт заголовок только для `Activity`, в котором находиться `WebView`? Или отдельно для каждого списка?

Comment: @akmaltilloev только для Activity, в котором находиться WebView

Comment: Но я хочу сделать для каждого списка, отдельую заголовку.

Comment: @akmaltilloev добавьте в код и посмотрите, что будет. У активити будет заголовок такой же как и у WebView

Comment: После ввода кода, программа при запуске и нажатии на список вылетает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64004/discussion-between-akmaltilloev-and-lex-hobbit).

Answer (score 0):

Нет кода в вашем вопросе, и что-то отвечать сложно. В целом, можете реализовать:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null){
    actionBar.setTitle("ЗАГОЛОВОК");
}
```

Там где ЗАГОЛОВОК можете указать массив строк, чтобы в соответствии с полученным номером из `Intent` задавать заголовок равный в массиве

Comment: Добавил код....